# Why doesn't this vim binding work?

Tags: macos, vim

I've [added these two lines to my vimrc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quickly_adding_and_deleting_empty_lines):

```
:nnoremap <silent><C-j> m`:silent +g/\m^\s*$/d<CR>``:noh<CR>
:nnoremap <silent><A-j> :set paste<CR>m`o<Esc>``:set nopaste<CR>
```

Upon saving and reloading the vimrc (`:so $MYVIMRC`), only the first binding works. The second does not work. The behavior I see is like the `A-j` just registers as a `j`, with the cursor moving down a line. My expected behavior is to see the a new line added below the cursor and a return to normal mode.

As context: I am using OS X's Terminal.app, and I have "Use option as meta key" turned on in its settings.

Comment: Do you only want to use option as the meta key for vim, or for other purposes as well?

Comment: I'd want to get this working and then figure it out

Comment: `<A->` mappings don't work reliably across environments and, specifically [in Mac OS X's terminal emulators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224269/546861) (`<A->` and `<M->` are equivalent). Use a different approach, like `:help mapleader`.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any luck getting alt/meta working on OSX. However, you can just use the multi-byte character that is mapped to by default (when option as meta is *not* selected). In the case of option-j, it's `∆`.

```
:nnoremap <silent>∆ :set paste<CR>m`o<Esc>``:set nopaste<CR>
```